# Fibre optic -physics

Tags: experimental-physics, fiber-optics

What is different between the lost of coupling and efficiency overall coupling ?

I know both of them (power out/power in)e.g (5%) that means is 5% light transmission and 95% lost.

Comment: Where did you read these terms? As far as I know, "lost of coupling" is not a widely used term in the fiber optics field. We could talk about *coupling efficiency* and *coupling loss*, maybe.

Comment: thanks for replaying me question.I believe, this calculation  base on the measuring  the power before the finer and after ?

Comment: there are coupling efficiency and coupling loss, how to calculated it?

Answer (score 0):

*Coupling efficiency* and *coupling loss* are essentially two different ways to describe the same thing.

The coupling efficiency is the portion of the incoming light in the first fiber that is coupled to the desired mode(s) in the second fiber.
$$\eta = \frac{P_{\rm out}}{P_{\rm in}}$$
Coupling efficiency is usually expressed as a numerical value (as shown above) or as a percentage. It might also be expressed in decibels.

Coupling loss is just the same thing, but usually expressed in decibels as a positive number.

For example, in your example we could say the system has "coupling efficiency of 0.05", or "5% coupling efficiency" or "-13 dB coupling efficiency" or "13 dB coupling loss". Conceivably you could also say "95% coupling loss".